# How to handle authentication in next.js 12?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

We need to add authentication to existing **next.js version 12** app. We have rest api which returns access and refresh token, we cant store them in local storage cuz we are not able to get them when we render pages on server. Also we have conditional rendering based on user logged in or not. The question is how to store tokens?

The problem is we can't change back end logic

Comment: The restrictions you've added make doing anything possible.  Although, cookies sound like what you're probably looking for, but you need to change your backend logic to add a `set-cookie` header with the token. Without clarification it's not clear if that change is acceptable in your situation. If you can clarify, I can explain more in an answer.

Comment: @akdombrowski thank you for answer, let's imagine we can add `set-cookie`

Comment: Ok, if you update the question, I can add a bit more in an answer. But, let's see if this could work for you. Basically, the backend sends the token(s) with the `set-cookie` header. Then when a request is made to the backend, it'll include the cookie. Your backend reads the cookie and now has the token(s) to decide what to render and send back to the frontend. There are significant security considerations to take, though. MDN's docs are an excellent resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies